# What is the quantum query complexity of the period finding routine of Shor's algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

It seems like it should be  a function of  N - O(log N), to minimise probability of getting a multiple of the period. However, Prof Preskill's lec notes mention:

> Thus we solve Period Finding if the sampled values of *k* have no common factor, which is true with high probability after a constant number of trials. Hence the quantum query complexity of Period Finding is constant (even better than for Simon's problem).

What am I missing?

Comment: "Query complexity" probably means number of oracle calls to calculate modular powers. Would you confirm it? Welcome to SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a periodic function $f(x+r) = f(x)$, the period-finding procedure of Shor's algorithm can find the period $r$ using ${O}(1)$ oracle calls and ${O}(poly(\log N))$ operations where a high probability of success is assured after repeating the procedure ${O}(\log \log r)$ times [1]. The number of times the procedure must be repeated is thus a small, constant number (of order ten or so). So, the quantum query complexity across *all* repetitions is ${O}(\log \log r)$ * ${O}(1)$, where ${O}(\log \log r)$ is constant time, so the result is still ${O}(1)$.

---

#### Derivation

Given $N$, we find a smooth $Q$ with $N^2 \leq Q < 2N^2$, wich implies that $Q/r > N$. Next, we put our machine in the uniform superposition of states representing numbers $x \text{ (mod } Q)$, and compute $a^x \text{ (mod } N)$ with a single application of $U:(x,y)\mapsto (x,y\oplus f(x))$, leaving the machine in state

$$\frac{1}{Q^{1/2}} \sum_{x=0}^{Q-1}|x, a^x \text{ (mod } N)\rangle.$$

We then apply the inverse quantum Fourier transform to the first register, producing the state

$$\frac{1}{Q}\sum_{x=0}^{Q-1}\exp{(2\pi i xc/Q)}|c, a^x \text{ (mod } N)\rangle.$$

Finally, we compute the probability that our machine ends in a particular state $|c, a^k \text{ (mod } N)\rangle$, where we may assume $0 \leq k < r$. Summing over all possible ways to reach this state, we find that the probability is

$$\bigg| \frac{1}{Q} \sum_{b=0}^{\lfloor (Q-k-1)/r \rfloor} \exp{(2\pi i brc/Q)} \bigg|^2.$$

The above probability is a simple explicit function of the integer $c$, whose magnitude has maxima when $c$ is close to integral multiples of $Q/r$. If $rc \text{ (mod } Q) \leq r/2$, this quantity can be shown to be asymptotically bounded below by $4/(\pi^2r^2)$, and thus at least $1/3r^2$. The probability of seeing a given state $|c, a^k \text{ (mod } N)\rangle$ will thus be at least $1/3r^2$ if there is a $d$ such that

$$\bigg|\frac{c}{Q} - \frac{d}{r} \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{2Q}.$$

Since $r < N$, and since any two distinct fractions with denominators less than $N$ must differ by at least $1/N^2$, a unique value of $d/r$ can be efficiently extracted from the known value of $c/Q$ by an application of the theory of continued fractions [2, Chapter X]. If we have the fraction $d/r$ in lowest terms, and if $d$ happens to be relatively prime to $r$, this will give us $r$.

There are $\phi(r)$ possible values for $d$ relatively prime to $r$, where $\phi$ is Euler's $\phi$ function. There are also $r$ possible values for $a^k$, since $r$ is the order of $a$. Thus, there are $r\phi(r)$ states $|c, a^k \text{ (mod } N)\rangle$ which would enable us to obtain $r$. Since each of these states occurs with probability at least $1/3r^2$, we obtain $r$ with probability at least $\phi(r)/3r$. Using the theorom that $\phi(r)/r > k/\log \log r$ for some fixed $k$ [2, Theorom 328], this shows that we find $r$ at least $k/\log \log r$ fraction of the time. *So, by repeating this procedure only ${O}(\log \log r)$ times, we are assured of a high probability of success* [1].

When $N$ is the product of two primes, the period $r$ is not only less than $N$ but also less than $\frac{1}{2}N$. As a result, a more extended analysis shows that the probability of learning a divisor $r$ from the measured value of $c$ is bounded from below not just by $4/\pi^2 \simeq 0.4$, but by more than 0.9. Furthermore, by adding a small number of additional qubits to the input register, the probability of learning a divisor $r$ in a single run can be made quite close to 1 [3].

---

[1] P. W. Shor, *Algorithms for quantum computation: discrete logarithms and factoring*, 1994. 
[2] G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, Fifth Edition,* Oxford University Press, 1979. 
[3] N. David Mermin, *Quantum Computer Science: an Introduction*. Cambridge University Press, 2016.

Comment: I understand the oracle is used once, and there are O((log)) operations required for the QFT in the circuit, as you've mentioned. But isn't there an there is another complexity involved - the measurement needs to be repeated some function of N times, to improve the probability of finding the correct period - what complexity is this called ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, the measurement does need to be repeated some number of times, however, this number depends on $r$, not $N$, and so when considering query and time complexity, is considered constant. I revised my answer to include this, along with brisk a derivation.

Comment: @Arun, let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: yes it does, thanks!

Comment: It is not the case that $O(\log \log r)$ is constant time, since $r$ is expected to be of size roughly similar to $N$. If you want $O(1)$ query complexity, you need to use some other technique: See for instance "On Shor's Quantum Factor Finding Algorithm: Increasing the Probability of Success and Tradeoffs Involving the Fourier Transform Modulus" by E. Knill for an early proposal.